# Curl command not working from centos Server

Tags: python, curl, centos, redhat

I try to execute the following curl command from centos to Redhat server. It returns the following error. But the same curl command working fine, when I'm directly executing it in RedHat server.

Curl Command:

> curl --cert client_cert.pem --key client_key.pem --cacert
>   server_cert.pem -u uname:pwd -X POST https:xyz.com/start -H
>   "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: */*" --data
>   '{"operationName": "Upload", "operationAlias": "Upload configuration
>   data from the network", "operationAttributes":
>   {"takeSranBtsFileBackups": true, "WS": "working_set2_32118"}}' -k

Error:

> "error": {"userMessage":"WebApplicationException:
>   com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body reader for Java
>   class
>   com.nokia.oss.configurator.rac.operationservice.webservice.rest.bindings.StartOperation,
>   and Java type class
>   com.nokia.oss.configurator.rac.operationservice.webservice.rest.bindings.StartOperation,
>   and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found. }
>   curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application; Name or service not known}

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: `https:example.com/start` looks like invalid URL, try `https://example.com/start` instead. Could you clarify your question and give reproducible example or additional details. May be network issues, may be DNS is down, or something else. And question has no relation with tag `python` in the current form.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.. Actually it was a typo. I'm using valid host only . it's throwing the above specified error while I'm trying to execute this curl command from a python script in Centos Server.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application; Name or service not known}
```

Looks like dns can't resolv https:xyz.com
Ok,your host is wrong format.
Use this format:
https://stackoverflow.com

or check your dns config in centos:

```
[root@pftest2 ~]# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 114.114.114.114
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.. Actually it was a typo. I'm using valid host only . it's throwing the above specified error while I'm trying to execute this curl command from a python script in Centos Server.